# Summation division property

Tags: calculus, summation

I have the following...

$$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i - p\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = p\sum_{i=1}^n (1-x_i)$$

And I'm told it can be re-written as so to isolate for $p$...

$$p = \dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$$

It is unclear to me why that is true. I tried to isolate $p$ but only got so far...

$$p = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i + \sum_{i=1}^n (1-x_i)}$$

Can someone explain to me what summation property is used and how it is used to isolate for $p$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the denominator in your expression for $p$ can be written as
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^n x_i + \sum_{i=1}^n (1-x_i) &= \sum_{i=1}^n x_i + \sum_{i=1}^n 1 - \sum_{i=1}^n x_i\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n x_i + n - \sum_{i=1}^n x_i = n.
\end{align*}
Thus, your expression becomes
$$
p = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i + \sum_{i=1}^n (1-x_i)}
= \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{n}.
$$

Comment: of course, not sure how I didn't put that together myself, thanks!